# How to get the previous and next object for a model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have a model called Post that looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

How would I get the previous and next Post objects?

I tried subtracting by 1 and adding by 1 to do a `.objects.get(id)` look up in the **views.py**:

```
def blog_detail(request, id):

    post = Post.objects.get(id)
    post_id = post.id
    previous_post_id = int((post.id-1))
    next_post_id = int((post.id+1))

    # Next post
    try:
        next_post = Post.objects.get(id=next_post_id)
    except:
        next_post = None

    # Previous Post
    try:
        previous_post = Post.objects.get(id=previous_post_id)
    except:
        previous_Post = None


    context = {'post': post, 'next': next_post, 'previous_post': previous_post}
    return render(request, "BlogHome/pages/post.html", context)
```

I am assuming I have a misunderstanding of how the syntax works.

Comment: Previous and next with respect to which/what?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye To any specific Post object, If I have a Post object where `Post.id == 2` I would get `Post.id == 1` and `Post.id == 3`. I have tried the [get_next_by_FOO()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) method, but it doesn't seem to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: How do you know that the id's would be 1 and 3? You should show what you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on concrete id's to exist in the database. They might have been deleted or the pk sequence could have been manipulated or they might have been skipped because of a failed transaction. You can do the following though:

```
# None if there's no previous
previous_post = Post.objects.filter(id__lt=post.id).order_by('-id').first()
# None if there's no next
next_post = Post.objects.filter(id__gt=post.id).order_by('id').first()
```

The first query gets the `Post` instance with the largest `id` smaller than `post`'s `id` if it exists. Note that the [get_next_by_FOO](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO) method only works with `DateField` and `DateTimeField`. You could, thus, use:

```
previous_post = post.get_previous_by_date()
next_post = post.get_next_by_date()
# both use id as tie-breaker
```

These will, however, raise exceptions if there is no next/previous.